# it is possible to create an application that notifies the user when accessing an specific url?

Tags: android

I intend to create an app that notifies the user when it accesses a specific url in the browser, Is it possible? how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no notification for when a user is navigating around within a browser. The only notification available is when a specific URL is opened in some other app (like email), and Android is looking for an app to run it. For that you can set up an activity and the user will get a list of options. This is how YouTube app is offered as an option for their own URLs.

Comment: I was thinking about creating this app for when the User enters into a website pop up a warning, this site is not recommended or this website is not reliable, you know?

Comment: Right, but if somebody is browsing around inside their browser app, you are not allowed to snoop at what they are doing. That would be a pretty bad security breach if Android allowed that.